# class variable and instance variable in cython

Tags: class, instance, cython

I am reading the cython documentation and get confused by the `_c_queue` and `self._c_queue` appeared in the following code. Does the class variable `_c_queue` play any role? The following code is from https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html

```
# distutils: sources = c-algorithms/src/queue.c
# distutils: include_dirs = c-algorithms/src/

cimport cqueue

cdef class Queue:
    cdef cqueue.Queue* _c_queue
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._c_queue = cqueue.queue_new()
        if self._c_queue is NULL:
            raise MemoryError()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self._c_queue is not NULL:
            cqueue.queue_free(self._c_queue)
```

Comment: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html _c_queue isn’t a class variable but a cdef attribute

Comment: Better: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html

Comment: Thanks, this reminds me in C language a variable could be declared first and initialized later. so `cdef cqueue.Queue* _c_queue` declares and `self._c_queue = cqueue.queue_new()` actually assigns the pointer. Furthermore, Extension type `cdef class` is actually a C struct, hence no such thing of a class variable involved at all. Each instance is a struct, and each `self` points to the struct itself. If one needs to share data between instances of an extension type, one could assign a pointer of the common data to the extension type constructor. Hope the understanding is correct.